# Dúvida sobre Expressão Regular

Tags: regex

Boa noite a todos.

Gostaria de saber de uma expressão regular para obter as seguintes informações:

Numeração e título de um capítulo.

Exemplo:

1. INTRODUÇÃO

número = 1.

título = INTRODUÇÃO

1.1. OBJETIVO GERAL

número = 1.1.

título = OBJETIVO GERAL

1.2. OBJETIVO ESPECÍFICO

número = 1.2.

título = OBJETIVO ESPECÍFICO

Preciso disso para gerar um sumário no seguinte formato:

1. |  INTRODUÇÃO         | PÁGINA

1.1. | OBJETIVO GERAL      | PÁGINA

1.2. | OBJETIVO ESPECÍFICO | PÁGINA

Ou seja, a expressão regular deverá ser capaz de reconhecer números seguido de pontos, no seguinte formato genérico:

Título Primário => x.

Título Secundário => x.x.

Título Terciário => x.x.x.

Título Quaternário => x.x.x.x.

E assim por diante.

Desde já agradeço a atenção. Abraço a todos.

Comment: Tentastes alguma ? E também dependendo, pode usar algum DOM parser...

Comment: Tentei esta: @"[\d]+[.]

Porém só está pegando o primeiro número e o primeiro ponto.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, estou utilizando a linguagem C#.

Comment: Utilizei este site: http://rubular.com/r/v5TNAzCQKa

Nele funciona, mas na hora de programar na aplicação está dando errado...

Comment: A propósito, o que é DOM parser? Procurei aqui e não encontrei ...

Comment: Peri, qui a pouco aparece...

Comment: Mas -- em que formato está o seu texto aí? Você sabe que o mais comum é o contrário, né? Marcaçoes especiais no texto do que é título, capítulo, etc... geram os números (e aí geram os títulos).

Comment: A resposta postada resolve o seu problema. Para testar expressões, use essa ferramenta online: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa expressão regular aqui resolve:

```
"^\s*?(?P<numero>(\d\.)+)\s*(?P<titulo>.*)$"
```

Você não disse que ferramenta vai usar para aplicar a expressão regular - esta pode ter alguma coisa específica das expressões regulares de Python - onde testei a mesma. A documentação está em: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Num prompt interativo de Python 3.5:

```
In [47]: import re

In [48]: a = """
    ...: 1.INTRODUÇÃO
    ...: número = 1.
    ...: 
    ...: título = INTRODUÇÃO
    ...: 
    ...: 1.1. OBJETIVO GERAL
    ...: 
    ...: número = 1.1.
    ...: título = OBJETIVO GERAL
    ...: 
    ...: 1.2. OBJETIVO ESPECÍFICO
    ...: 
    ...: 1.2.1. Detalhamento
    ...: 2. Outro Capítulo
    ...: """

In [49]: [(m.group('numero'), m.group('titulo')) for m in re.finditer(r"^\s*?(?P<numero>(\d\.)+)\s*(?P<titulo>.*)$", a, re.MULTILINE) ]
Out[49]: 
[('1.', 'INTRODUÇÃO'),
 ('1.1.', 'OBJETIVO GERAL'),
 ('1.2.', 'OBJETIVO ESPECÍFICO'),
 ('1.2.1.', 'Detalhamento'),
 ('2.', 'Outro Capítulo')]
```

(A função `re.finditer` devolve um iterador de "match objects" - esses por sua vez tem um método `group` que pode ser chamado com o nome do grupo desejado. O nome dos grupos, por sua vez, é dado dentro da própria expressão regular, usando a construção `(?P<nome>...)` )
Essa parte dos nomes dos grupos deve ser a única coisa que muda caso a ferramenta de regexp que você for usar seja diferente das regexps de Python.)

Comment: A partir do seu exemplo consegui obter a seguinte expressão regular que me atendeu:

^\s*((\d\.)+)

A partir dela teve como obter os números dos capítulo.

Muito obrigado jsbueno.